# Is there a way to load the picture from JSON url?

Tags: java, android

> I have a problem to load the picture into my application by JSON. I
>   can load all the content but pictures is missing.
>
> I update the full files that you can see wherever is the problem.
>   Thanks a lot

This is the file who parsing the json data. I try with Glide as some suggestion said. Not working cause I don't know glide.with(mcontext) --> give me an error can resolve the symbol mcontext

package com.example.administrator.superclass.Activity_User;

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.chad.library.adapter.base.BaseQuickAdapter;
import com.chad.library.adapter.base.BaseViewHolder;
import com.example.administrator.superclass.R;
import com.example.administrator.superclass.User_data;
import com.example.administrator.superclass.Utils.Exlist;
import com.example.administrator.superclass.Utils.Gridmanager;
import com.example.administrator.superclass.Utils.Okhttp_Util;
import com.example.administrator.superclass.Utils.ProgressDialog_Util;
import com.example.administrator.superclass.Utils.Toast_util;
import com.scwang.smartrefresh.layout.SmartRefreshLayout;
import com.scwang.smartrefresh.layout.api.RefreshLayout;
import com.scwang.smartrefresh.layout.listener.OnRefreshListener;
import com.youth.banner.Banner;
import com.youth.banner.loader.ImageLoader;

import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Home_home extends Fragment {
    private Banner homeBanner;
    private RecyclerView homeClassRecy;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Home_class_gs home_class_gs;

    Home_class_recy home_class_recy;

    Home_descovery_grid_recy home_descovery_grid_recy;
    Home_descovery_grid_gs home_descovery_grid_gs;
    RecyclerView homeDiscovery;
    List<Home_descovery_grid_gs> grid_gsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RelativeLayout homeBookpl;
    SmartRefreshLayout smartRefreshLayout;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_home, null);
        if(!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)){
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }
        initView(view);

        return view;
    }


    private void initView(View view) {
        homeBookpl = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.home_bookpl);
        homeBanner = (Banner) view.findViewById(R.id.home_banner);
        homeClassRecy = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_class_recy);
        homeBanner.setDelayTime(5000);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        homeClassRecy.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        homeDiscovery = view.findViewById(R.id.home_discovery);
        smartRefreshLayout=view.findViewById(R.id.home_smartre);
        Gridmanager gridmanager=new Gridmanager(getActivity(),2);
        gridmanager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        homeDiscovery.setLayoutManager(gridmanager);

        homeBookpl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),Places.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        smartRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh(@NonNull RefreshLayout refreshLayout) {
                initData();
                refreshLayout.finishRefresh(2000);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initData() {
        final Loadbanner loadbanner = new Loadbanner();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String addata = Okhttp_Util.Ok_Get(getActivity(),"https://www.superclass.ltd/show_all_advertising.php");
                if (!addata.equals("")){
                    try {
                        JSONObject adjsonObject = new JSONObject(addata);
                        JSONArray adjsonArray = adjsonObject.getJSONArray("AD");
                        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < adjsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            list.add((String) adjsonArray.get(i));
                        }
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                    homeBanner.setImageLoader(loadbanner);
                                    homeBanner.setImages(list).start();
                            }
                        });
                        initDescovery();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast_util.Toast_show(getActivity(),"网络似乎有问题！");

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    //轮播初始化
    private class Loadbanner extends ImageLoader {
        @Override
        public void displayImage(Context context, Object path, ImageView imageView) {
            try {
                Glide.with(getActivity()).load(path).into(imageView);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("轮播", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    //使用eventbus发送活动内容
    public class SetDiscoverydata {
        Home_descovery_grid_gs mapdata;
        int postion;
        public SetDiscoverydata(Home_descovery_grid_gs mapdata,int postion) {
            this.mapdata = mapdata;
            this.postion=postion;
        }
    }

    //使用eventbus发送课程内容
    public class Setcompanyclass {
        Home_class_gs companyclassdata;

        public Setcompanyclass(Home_class_gs companyclassdata) {
            this.companyclassdata = companyclassdata;
        }
    }

    private void initDescovery() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<Home_class_gs> class_gsList = new ArrayList<>();
                String classdata = Okhttp_Util.Ok_Get(getActivity(),"https://www.superclass.ltd/show_fast_class.php");
                try {
                    JSONObject classjsonObject = new JSONObject(classdata);
                    JSONArray classjsonArray = classjsonObject.getJSONArray("fastclasses");
                    for (int i = 0; i < classjsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) classjsonArray.get(i);
                        home_class_gs = new Home_class_gs();
                        home_class_gs.setAddress(jsonObject1.getString("address"));
                        home_class_gs.setCompanyimage(jsonObject1.getString("companyimage"));
                        home_class_gs.setCompanyname(jsonObject1.getString("companyname"));
                        home_class_gs.setTypename(jsonObject1.getString("typename"));
                        home_class_gs.setImagepath(jsonObject1.getString("imagepath"));
                        home_class_gs.setStars(jsonObject1.getString("stars"));


                        String imagepath = jsonObject1.getString("imagepath");
                        String coming = jsonObject1.getString("companyimage");

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            Glide.with(mcontext).load(coming).into(home_class_gs);

                        }

                        if (!User_data.sxlist.isEmpty()){
                            if (User_data.sxlist.contains(home_class_gs.getTypename())){
                                class_gsList.add(home_class_gs);
                            }
                        }else {
                            class_gsList.add(home_class_gs);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        home_class_recy = new Home_class_recy(R.layout.item_home_class_recy, class_gsList);
                        homeClassRecy.setAdapter(home_class_recy);
                        home_class_recy.setEmptyView(R.layout.empty, homeClassRecy);
                        home_class_recy.setOnItemClickListener(new BaseQuickAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(BaseQuickAdapter adapter, View view, int position) {
                                EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new Setcompanyclass(class_gsList.get(position)));
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Company_class.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                grid_gsList.clear();
                try {
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put("username", User_data.user);
                    String discovery = Okhttp_Util.Ok_Post(getActivity(),"https://www.superclass.ltd/show_discovery.php", hashMap);

                    JSONObject disjsonobj = new JSONObject(discovery);
                    JSONArray disjsonarr = disjsonobj.getJSONArray("actors");
                    for (int i = 0; i < disjsonarr.length(); i++) {
                        home_descovery_grid_gs = new Home_descovery_grid_gs();
                        JSONObject dis = (JSONObject) disjsonarr.get(i);
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setId(dis.getString("discover_id"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setTitle(dis.getString("title"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setAddress(dis.getString("address"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setDate(dis.getString("date"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setWhatwedo(dis.getString("whatwedo"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setWhatyouneed(dis.getString("whatyouneed"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setWhocanjoin(dis.getString("whocanjoin"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setImagepath(dis.getString("imagepath"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setImage_path2(dis.getString("image_path2"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setImage_path3(dis.getString("image_path3"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setNumbers(dis.getString("numbers"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setCompanyname(dis.getString("companyname"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setTime(dis.getString("time"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setLike(dis.getString("like"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setPhone(dis.getString("phone"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setWebsite(dis.getString("website"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setCompanyimagepath(dis.getString("companyimagepath"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setAboutus(dis.getString("aboutus"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setType(dis.getString("type"));
                        home_descovery_grid_gs.setArea_name(dis.getString("area_name"));
                        Log.e("User_data.sxlist: ",User_data.sxlist.toString() );
                        if (!User_data.sxlist.isEmpty()){
                            if (User_data.sxlist.contains(home_descovery_grid_gs.getType())){
                                grid_gsList.add(home_descovery_grid_gs);
                                User_data.like_descovery.add(grid_gsList);
                            }
                        }else {
                            grid_gsList.add(home_descovery_grid_gs);
                            User_data.like_descovery.add(grid_gsList);
                        }
                    }
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            home_descovery_grid_recy=new Home_descovery_grid_recy(R.layout.item_home_discovery,grid_gsList);
                            homeDiscovery.setAdapter(home_descovery_grid_recy);
                            home_descovery_grid_recy.setOnItemClickListener(new BaseQuickAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(BaseQuickAdapter adapter, View view, int position) {
                                    Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),Home_discovery.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new SetDiscoverydata(grid_gsList.get(position),position));
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this))
            EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void GetF_Key(Filter.SendKey data){
        if (data.F_key.equals("init")){
            initDescovery();
        }
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void deletlike(Like_descovery.Deletdeslike data){
        for (int i = 0; i < grid_gsList.size(); i++) {
            if (data.res.equals(grid_gsList.get(i).getId())){
                Log.e( "deletlike: ","a" );
                grid_gsList.get(i).setLike("0");
                home_descovery_grid_recy.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser){
            initData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean by picture missing? Two ways to do this, either your json return the picture url and issue another http call to load the image or your image encode to string like base64 and decode back to picture after receive it.

Comment: Hi Joey, I mean by pictures missing. That when i load the app to my phone. I get everything from Json. But only the picture through the URL not download. So am sure in okhttp_util ok_get I'm missing something. I will share how i grab picture from home page for example . Thanks a lot for your help appreciate that

Comment: use GSON for mapping data and simply use Glide.with(context)
            .load(model.getUrl())
            .into(imageView)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso).

parse the url and load the image -

```
String url = jsonObj.getString("imagepath")

Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(url)
            .into(imageView)
```

or

```
Picasso.get()
       .load(url)
       .into(holder.contImg)
```

Answer (score 1):

First sync gradle file

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
```

Second put Internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

And third and last define Picasso or glide to load the image.

```
String comimg = home_class_gs.setImagepath(jsonObject1.getString("companyimage"));   
String imgpath = home_class_gs.setImagepath(jsonObject1.getString("imagepath"));

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
   Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(comimg)
            .into(imageView) //Sometime picasso dont load image below 5.0

   Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(imgpath)
            .into(imageView) //Sometime picasso dont load image below 5.0


}else{

Picasso.get()
       .load(comimg)
       .into(holder.contImg)

Picasso.get()
       .load(imgpath)
       .into(holder.contImg)
}
```

Comment: Add sayyed. I got the idea. But not a specialist of Android. When i write Glide.with(mContext) ---> give me an error cannot resolve symbol. I will add the full files. If you can have a look on it. Thanks a lot and wish you also a good day

Comment: define in initData()  just below where you are getting the imageurl string . and define string in .load(imageurl) in Glide...